# Can a particle with non-zero angular momentum pass through the center of a spherical potential?

Tags: classical-mechanics, angular-momentum, potential-energy

Suppose you have a particle of mass $m$ moving in a potential $V(r) = -\frac{k}{r^2}$, with $r^2 = x^2+y^2+z^2$ and $k > 0$. Since the angular momentum $l$ is conserved, the particle will move in a plane: Let's use polar coordinates $(r, \theta)$. The expression for the energy is then:

$$
E = \frac12m\dot{r}^2+\left(\frac{l^2}{2m}-k\right)\frac1{r^2}
$$

Suppose $l < \sqrt{2mk}$. Then the effective potential is of the form $V_{eff} = -\frac{a}{r^2}$ with $a > 0$.

This implies that no matter what the initial energy $E$ of the particle is, it can and will at some point pass through $r=0$. Indeed, if you find the trajectory $r = r(\theta)$, you get things that look like either $r = \cos \theta$ or like $r = \sinh \theta$, which are $0$ at some point.

I don't understand how this can be. When the particle is very close to $r=0$, its momentum has to pointed towards $r=0$, but this would imply that $\vec{r}$ and $\vec{p}$ are parallel, and so $l$ would be $0$! How can this be? Doesn't conservation of angular momentum prevent the particle from reaching the center, no matter how strong the potential is?

Comment: Random fact that is vaguely relevant: a $r^{-5}$ potential has circular orbits that pass through the origin. OF course energy diverges there and if material bodies were involved there would be a crash, but still...

Comment: This wiki article has general solutions for radial potentials : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_central-force_problem#General_solution

Answer (score 1):

The constraint on angular momentum is $l=mr^2\dot{\theta}=\text{constant}$. As $r\rightarrow0$, we have $\dot{\theta}\rightarrow\infty$. This does cause the kinetic energy to diverge, but the potential energy blows up to $-\infty$, so the total energy stays constant.

Answer (score 1):

$\vec r$ and $\vec p$ cannot be parallel. If you take a basis $\vec e_r, \vec e_\theta$, the coordinates of $\vec r$ and $\vec p$ are :

$$\vec r = \begin{pmatrix} r\\ 0 \end{pmatrix}, \quad  \vec p = \begin{pmatrix} m \dot r\\ m  r \dot \theta\end{pmatrix} \tag{1}$$

The angular momentum $l = m r^2 \dot \theta$ is constant, and here, we will suppose that it is different of zero $l \neq 0$ (otherwise your question is trivial), so we may write :

$$\vec r = \begin{pmatrix} r\\ 0 \end{pmatrix}, \quad  \vec p = \begin{pmatrix} m \dot r\\ \frac{l}{r}\end{pmatrix} \tag{2}$$

You see that it is not possible, for any finite value of $r$, including $r=0$, that $\vec r$ and $\vec p$ are parallel, because $\frac{l}{r} \neq 0$ (For $r=0$, we may say that $\frac{l}{r} = \pm \infty$, but $\pm\infty \neq 0$)

[EDIT]

A different point of view is using the variable $u = \frac{1}{r}$. The equations of movement are then :

$$ \frac{d^2u}{d \theta^2} + u = \frac{2mk}{l^2}u \tag{3}$$

If $l^2 > 2mk$, there is a solution $u = A ~cos (\omega \theta) + B sin (\omega \theta)$, with $\omega^2 = 1 -  \frac{2mk}{l^2}$

If $l^2 < 2mk$, there is a solution $u = A ~ch (\omega \theta) + B sh (\omega \theta)$, with $\omega^2 =    \frac{2mk}{l^2} - 1$

If $l^2 = 2mk$, there is a solution $u = A + B \theta$

Comment: The OP has written the $\frac{1}{2}m r^2 \dot{\theta}^2$ term as $\frac{l^2}{2mr^2}$, since $l = m r^2 \dot{\theta}$ is conserved.

Comment: I understand what the math says. I'm having trouble picturing it; thinking about it geometrically, it seems to me that the angular momentum should be zero right before passing through the origin, but that's probably because it's not easy to see how an infinite angular velocity would work.

Comment: @JavierBadia : I edited the answer. maybe you will find it useful.